# Bash forked for loop with while loop control

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop

I have a `for` loop that will cycle through all the files in a directory. I want to run a process on each file (in this example `echo` file name and `sleep 5`). However I want to be able to run this 5 files at a time (in the background with `&`). The problem is I can't figure out how to iterate `$f` within the `while` loop so that I don't end up processing the same file five times instead of five different files at the same time.

```
#!/bin/bash

maxjobs=5

for f in `ls /home/user/`
do
 jobsrunning=0
  while [ $jobsrunning -lt $maxjobs ]
  do
    echo "Converting file"$f 
    sleep 5 & #wait for 5 seconds 
    jobsrunning=$((jobsrunning + 1))
    echo $jobsrunning
  done
wait
done
```

Comment: you never reset `jobsrunning` to 0. But a much better solution exists to "feed" files to a process. Search here for `find print0 xargs`. Unfortuantely the final term might be `multiple, jobs, -n` or a few others.

Comment: Please [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: no need for `ls ...` subshell with for.    "for f in /home/user/*"  suffices - difference with ls is that names will be fully qualified, therefore not a drop-in replacement. May be preferable in your case because actions on those files needed to know the implied "/home/user" location as your current solution requires

Comment: "so that I don't end up processing the same file five times instead of five different files at the same time" make not a lot of sense. why would you process the same file five times? Why would, when printed to screen, the same file name appear 5 times?

Comment: @Bushmills because of the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really just need to reset `jobsrunning`, and I don't think you need the inner loop at all. It's just a condition.

```
#!/bin/bash

maxjobs=5
jobsrunning=0
for f in /home/user/*; do
    if (( jobsrunning >= maxjobs )); then
        wait
        jobsrunning=0
    fi
    echo "converting"
    sleep 5 & # wait for how many seconds?
    (( jobsrunning++ ))
    echo "$jobsrunning"
done
wait
```

That said, this sounds like a job for [parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Comment: This doesn't quite work, the `jobsrunning` needs to be defined before the `if` statement. I'm getting loads of errors when trying to run it.

Comment: @crysis405 Well, explicit may be better, but an undefined name evaluates to `0` in shell arithmetic context, so this should work fine. However, if you just used `[ ]` as in your original code, then yes, you need to define it. Why not switch to modern arithmetic expressions, though?

Comment: I'm in Ubuntu 12.04 and I can't seem to get this to work. Do I need to update something?

Comment: `./test_par.sh: 2: ./test_par.sh: jobsrunning: not found
converting`
`./test_par.sh: 8: ./test_par.sh: jobsrunning++: not found` `test_par.sh` is the file I pasted this into (assuming that's correct)

Comment: Still getting the same error. The way I am executing this is `sh test_par.sh`

Comment: just tested it on another computer and your code works, must be something in my ubuntu installation.

Comment: @crysis405 you can't invoke a *bash* script as *sh*. Those are two different languages, and that is why you are having that problem.